# Angular RouteProvider redirect to another html file

Tags: angularjs, redirect, route-provider

I have to build an app for an existing website, but unfortunately the website (outside of my control) detects the user device and redirects to a mobile version.

I am trying to reuse the same js file but different html files.

So I have:

1. index.html for desktop
2. mobile.html for mobile

both call init.js where I want to handle my logic, my problem is that for some reason the routing is not working as I expected and I cannot figure out why.

Desktop:

1. I go to example.com
2. get redirect to example.com/#/steps/age/0
3. Refresh the page and it stays in example.com/#/steps/age/0

This works as expected

Mobile:

1. I go to example.com/mobile.html
2. get redirect to example.com/mobile.html#/steps/age/0
3. Refresh the page and instead of staying in the same url, it goes to example.com/steps/age/0#/steps/age/0

This does not work as expected (expected to stay in the same url once refreshing as in the step number 2)

Code below:

```
angular
.module('profileToolApp', ["ngRoute", "ngResource", "ngSanitize"])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/steps/:steps*', {
        templateUrl : 'profile-app.html',
        controller : 'example'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/steps/age/0'
    });
})
.controller('example', function($scope, $routeParams, $resource, $location){
    console.log("example controller");
});
```

Can anyone please advise?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is examining the entire path to see where it should route to. So when you have `example.com/mobile.html#/steps/age/0` There is no matching route, so it substitutes the route for you, in place of `mobile.html` so you get `/steps/age/0#/steps/age/0` from your `otherwise`. The fundamental problem is that angular has no sense of what `mobile.html` means, and takes it as a parameter.

One solution is to use routes to separate your pages.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'desktop.html', //was 'index.html pre edit
        controller : 'example'
    })
    .when('/mobile/', {
        templateUrl : 'mobile.html',
        controller : 'example'
    })
    .when('/steps/:steps*', {
        templateUrl : 'profile-app.html',
        controller : 'example'
    })
    .when('/mobile/steps/:steps*', {
        templateUrl : 'mobile-profile-app.html',
        controller : 'example'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
})
```

Controllers may vary as needed.

Alternatives to this are to have `mobile.html` use its own angular App and routing, which may be beneficial since you won't run into desktop directives leaking into mobile. You can inject all of your directives and controllers into it, but still have a nice separation of index and mobile. You can take that a step further and have a redirect to `m.example.com`, but that's a different topic.

**EDIT** I made a mistake. Having `templateUrl` be `index.html` is a bit wrong. `index.html` should contain your `ng-app` and your `ng-view` directives, possibly a controller. Any common html should reside there. `desktop.html` and `mobile.html` should contain the specific HTML for those platforms.

As an afterthought, Within those you could have a directive called `profile` that does all of your profile work, and with a bit of `ng-switch` you can have that appear if `steps` is defined in the scope, and use:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/steps?/:steps?', {
    templateUrl : 'desktop.html', //was 'index.html pre edit
    controller : 'example'
})
.when('/mobile/steps?/:steps?', {
    templateUrl : 'mobile.html',
    controller : 'example'
})
```

But now I'm rambling, I'm not 100% sure that will work tbh. **END EDIT**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this makes sense, forces me to rewrite a lot of the app though :( well... Let's do it, thank you again.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider you might be able to use optional named groups to save a bit of work. Try `.when(/mobile?/steps/:steps*)`. I don't know enough about how you're differentiating your pages to really be a lot of help, but you should be able to reuse a lot of code even with the changes I have here. I also just noticed a bit of a mistake... Fixing.

Comment: Thanks Roman I did notice the code was slightly off but I did understand what you were saying so I change my approach to the problem instead, but ultimately that did not work either, the problem was a conflict with jQuery Mobile (was trying to use their slider) with AngularJS, Jquery Mobile was trying to handle the routing that's why my Angular routing wasn't working, thank you anyway for all the effort and help.